# Get instant results from dropdownlist with jquery/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want my dropdown list to automatically collect the right results from a database without refreshing the page.

I wrote code with jQuery but somehow it calls my front-end twice instead of calling the results of a select statement.

Here's my javasacript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function ajaxLoaded(response) {
        $('#performanceResults').html(response);
    }
    function doRequest() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "results.php",
            type: 'POST',
            success: ajaxLoaded
        });
    }
    $('#performance').change(doRequest);
});
```

This is the method that contains my form:

```
public function SelectPerformanceIndicator() {
        $this->getResults ();

        $str = '<form >';
        $str .= 'Select your performance indicator<br>';
        $str .= '<select id = "performance">';
        $str .= '<option value = "">Select Performance Indicator</option>';
        $str .= '<option value = "1">Cost per auction  </option>';
        $str .= '<option value = "2">Fillrate </option>';
        $str .= '</select>';
        $str .= '</form>';
        $str .= '<br>';
        $str .= '<div id="performanceResults"></div>';

        return $str;
    }
```

And this is the method that should create a table depending on which value I select in my front-end.

```
public function getResults() {
        $intCase = intval ( $_POST ['q'] );

        if ($intCase == 1 or $intCase == 2) {
            if ($intCase == 1) {
                $strSql = 'select bidder_id, won, lost, fillrate, costs, cost_auction from result_bidder where tagload = ( select max(tagload) from result_bidder) order by cost_auction asc limit 1';
            }
            if ($intCase == 2) {
                $strSql = 'select bidder_id, won, lost, fillrate, costs, cost_auction from result_bidder where tagload = ( select max( tagload ) from result_bidder ) order by fillrate asc limit 1';
            }
            if (! isset ( $_POST ['jquery'] )) {
                $arrBestPerformer = $objDatabase->queryresult ( $strSql );
                echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>bidder_id</th>
            <th>won</th>
            <th>lost</th>
            <th>fillrate</th>
            <th>costs</th>
            <th>cost_auction</th>
            </tr>";

                while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $arrBestPerformer ) ) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row ['bidder_id'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row ['won'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row ['lost'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row ['fillrate'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row ['costs'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row ['cost_auction'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

Edit  to clarify current results:

Front-end without selecting a value in the drop-down:

```
Image

Dropdownlist

Results of a simulation
```

Front-end with selecting a value in the drop-down:

```
Image

Dropdownlist

*Image

*Dropdownlist

*Results of a simulation
```

**This is where jquery calls the front-end twice**

Comment: a bit confusing, can you clarify please? what is the current result and how would you like it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, you should use a jQuery Plugin called Chosen, that does exactly this. Look to http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function ajaxLoaded(response) {
        $('#performanceResults').html(response);
    }
    function doRequest() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "results.php",
            type: 'POST',
            success: ajaxLoaded()
        });
    }
    $('#performance').change(doRequest());
});
```